# Observing change between in-line and full screen modes

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I'm using the iOS YouTube helper library to display a video in-line within a table view cell. Whenever the YTPlayerView exits full screen mode, the content offset of my tableview is slightly off. I suspect it's related to the YTPlayerView hiding the status bar or something that's messing with the  offset. Has anyone experienced this? I want to try to manually set the content offset whenever the YTPlayerView exits full screen, but I'm stumped on how to observe this. ViewWillAppear on my tableview controller doesn't get called and the NSNotifications I tried didn't work. There doesn't appear to be a delegate method on YTPlayerView for this, either.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification

in your viewcontroller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enteredFullScreen:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullScreen:)  name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification object:nil];
```

have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get this to work using these notifications and manually res-setting the tableview content insets. Not in love with how the cells jump down after dismissing full screen video (looks a bit amateurish) but I guess it will do.